# Merge multiple rows into one with more than one row value in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently building a query to retrieve some data from my db, I need to access some information with a common id in just one row.

With this query:

```
select 
        missions_answer.response_id as "response",
        crm_player."document" as "document",
        missions_question.label as "label",
        missions_answertext.body as "bill #",
        missions_answerselectmultiple.body as "product",
        missions_answerinteger.body as "answer" 
from missions_answer 
    left join missions_question on missions_answer.question_id = missions_question.id 
    left join missions_answertext on missions_answer.id = missions_answertext.answer_ptr_id 
    left join missions_answerselectmultiple on missions_answer.id = missions_answerselectmultiple.answer_ptr_id
    left join missions_answerinteger on missions_answer.id = missions_answerinteger.answer_ptr_id 
    left join missions_response on missions_answer.response_id = missions_response.id
    left join crm_player on missions_response.player_id = crm_player.id
    LEFT JOIN crm_user ON crm_player.user_id = crm_user.id
    where  missions_answer.response_id = '71788176'
    group by missions_answer.response_id, crm_player.document,missions_answertext.body,
        missions_question.label,
        missions_answerselectmultiple.body ,
        missions_answerinteger.body,
        crm_user.first_name,
        crm_user.last_name
```

This is what I currently have:

```
+   response    +     document    +    label    +    bill #  +    product  +  answer
-   71788176    -     79907201    -    bill #   -    26899   -             -
-   71788176    -     79907201    -    amount   -            -             -    1
-   71788176    -     79907201    -    product  -      -    {"name": "Shoes"}   -
-   71788176    -     79907201    -    price    -            -             -  25.99
```

This is what I'm looking for:

```
+   response    +     document    +    bill #  +    product  +  amount  +   price 
-   71788176    -     79907201    -    26899   -     shoes   -       1  -   25.99
```

I've been trying to use `crosstab` but I'm still unable to find it, thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: Will a response always have exactly one product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your current state you simply can do the pivot using the `FILTER` clause:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2864950e78db6b25d1876fbbe6949fdf)

```
SELECT
    response,
    document,
    MAX(bill) FILTER (WHERE label = 'bill') as bill,
    MAX(answer) FILTER (WHERE label = 'amount') as amount,
    MAX(product) FILTER (WHERE label = 'product') as product,
    MAX(answer) FILTER (WHERE label = 'price') as price
FROM t
GROUP BY response, document
```

---

I am not quite sure, how your original table looks like. If it is more like this:

```
response | document | label   | value
-------: | -------: | :------ | :----
71788176 | 79907201 | bill    | 26899
71788176 | 79907201 | amount  | 1    
71788176 | 79907201 | product | shoes
71788176 | 79907201 | price   | 25.99
```

Then you can modify the query like this:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6dfb7bbd8ca0425ae1fceb6bad734bca)

```
SELECT
    response,
    document,
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE label = 'bill') as bill,
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE label = 'amount') as amount,
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE label = 'product') as product,
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE label = 'price') as price
FROM t
GROUP BY response, document
```

---

**Edit**: TO added the JSON value to product column:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8d5ec30e6a05ae76bdf3a0a8c8cf9ca3)

Variant 1: You could simply cast the type `json` into type `text`:

```
MAX(product::text) FILTER (WHERE label = 'product') as product,
```

Variant 2: You read the value from the `"name"` attribute:

```
MAX(product ->> 'name') FILTER (WHERE label = 'product') as product,
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I'm getting an error applying MAX to the JSON cell that has the product, got any idea?

Comment: JSON must be treated a little different. Please edit your question and append some real input data. Where is the JSON data, how does it look like, what is your expected output