# math operations between row values during group by statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, left-join, aggregate-functions

In this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908661/merge-multiple-rows-into-one-with-more-than-one-row-value-in-a-column) I was trying to group my products in the way they currently are.

Now I'm trying to group all the products of my query with the sum of all the products sold and the mean price in each case, this is how it looks:

[image]

This is my query:

```
select 
        missions_answer.response_id as Response,
        crm_player."document" as Document,
        MAX(missions_answerselectmultiple.body::json ->> 'name') FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'Producto') as Product,
        MAX(missions_answerinteger.body) FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'Cantidad unidades vendidas') as Amount,
        MAX(missions_answerinteger.body) FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'Valor Unidad') as Price
from missions_answer 
    left join missions_question on missions_answer.question_id = missions_question.id 
    left join missions_answertext on missions_answer.id = missions_answertext.answer_ptr_id 
    left join missions_answerselectmultiple on missions_answer.id = missions_answerselectmultiple.answer_ptr_id
    left join missions_answerinteger on missions_answer.id = missions_answerinteger.answer_ptr_id 
    left join missions_response on missions_answer.response_id = missions_response.id
    left join crm_player on missions_response.player_id = crm_player.id
    LEFT JOIN crm_user ON crm_player.user_id = crm_user.id
    group by Response, Document
```

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
+ ----------------------- + ---------- + ---------- + 
-       product           + total_sold + mean_price +
+ ----------------------- + ---------- + ---------- + 
+ Perfiles- Esquinera.... +    669.000 +    2.500   +
+ Traslucent...           +   900.000  +    30.000  +
```

And so on for all products in the table, the fact is I've been unable to sum all prices multiplied for the amount during the grouping and as well calculating the mean price for each product case in the table.

I'm trying this:

```
select 
        MAX(missions_answerselectmultiple.body::json ->> 'name') FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'Producto') as Product,
        MAX(missions_answerinteger.body) FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'Cantidad unidades vendidas') as Amount,
        MAX(missions_answerinteger.body) FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'Valor Unidad') as Price,
        sum( (MAX(missions_answerinteger.body) FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'Valor Unidad')) * (MAX(missions_answerinteger.body) FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label )= 'Cantidad unidades vendidas')  ) as Total
from missions_answer 
    left join missions_question on missions_answer.question_id = missions_question.id 
    left join missions_answertext on missions_answer.id = missions_answertext.answer_ptr_id 
    left join missions_answerselectmultiple on missions_answer.id = missions_answerselectmultiple.answer_ptr_id
    left join missions_answerinteger on missions_answer.id = missions_answerinteger.answer_ptr_id 
    left join missions_response on missions_answer.response_id = missions_response.id
    left join crm_player on missions_response.player_id = crm_player.id
    LEFT JOIN crm_user ON crm_player.user_id = crm_user.id
    group by Product
```

But I get

```
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested
```

Hope anybody can help me, thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: what is the problem? sum(axb) should work. Remove NULL values if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need another level of aggregation:

```
select product, sum(amount) as total_sold, avg(price) as mean_price
from (
    select 
        ma.response_id as response,
        cp."document" as document,
        max(mas.body::json ->> 'name') filter(where mq.label = 'Producto') as Product,
        max(mai.body) filter(where mq.label = 'Cantidad unidades vendidas') as Amount,
        MAX(mai.body) filter(where mq.label = 'Valor Unidad') as Price
    from missions_answer ma
    left join missions_question             mq  on ma.question_id = mq.id 
    left join missions_answertext           mat on ma.id = mat.answer_ptr_id 
    left join missions_answerselectmultiple mas on ma.id = mas.answer_ptr_id
    left join missions_answerinteger        mai on ma.id = mai.answer_ptr_id 
    left join missions_response             mr  on ma.response_id = mr.id
    left join crm_player                    cp  on mr.player_id = cp.id
    left join crm_user                      cu  on cp.user_id = cu.id
    group by response, document
) t
group by product
```

Note that I changed the query to use table aliases for all tables; this shortens the code, and makes it easier to follow.

Comment: It works, thank you so much for your answer! But as ```total_sold```  I'm referring to the multiplication of ```amount * price```, tried to replace  ```sum(amount)``` with  ```sum(amount * price)``` in the first line, but I get ```ERROR: integer out of range```, got any idea?