# merge multiple rows grouping by miliseconds in timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is a variation of a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908661/merge-multiple-rows-into-one-with-more-than-one-row-value-in-a-column) I made. I'm currently building a query to retrieve some data from my db, I need to access some information with a common id in just one row.

With this query:

```
select 
        missions_answer.response_id as "response",
        missions_answer.created as date,
        crm_player."document" as "document",
        missions_question.label as "label",
        missions_answertext.body as "bill #",
        missions_answerselectmultiple.body as "product",
        missions_answerinteger.body as "answer" 
from missions_answer 
    where  missions_answer.response_id = '71788176'
    group by missions_answer.response_id, crm_player.document,missions_answertext.body,
        missions_question.label,
        missions_answerselectmultiple.body ,
        missions_answerinteger.body,
        crm_user.first_name,
        crm_user.last_name
        order by date
```

This is what I currently have:

```
+   response    +          date        +   document    +    label    +    bill #  +    product  +  answer
-   71788176    -2020-07-29 19:05:41:00-     79907201    -    bill #   -    26899   -             -
-   71788176    -2020-07-29 19:05:41:01-     79907201    -    amount   -            -             -    1
-   71788176    -2020-07-29 19:05:41:02-     79907201    -    product  -      -    Shoes 1   -
-   71788176    -2020-07-29 19:05:41:03-     79907201    -    price    -            -             -  25.99
-   71788176    -2020-07-29 19:05:41:04-     79907201    -    amount   -            -             -    10
-   71788176    -2020-07-29 19:05:41:05-     79907201    -    product  -      -    Shoes 2   -
-   71788176    -2020-07-29 19:05:41:06-     79907201    -    price    -            -             -  32.00
```

Notice the order: `amount` then `product name` then `price` for each product, given by the miliseconds in `date` field.

Using `filter`in my query:

```
select 
        missions_answer.response_id as Response,
        crm_player."document" as document,        
        MAX(missions_answertext.body) FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'bill #') as "bill #",
        MAX(missions_answerselectmultiple.body::json ->> 'name') FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'product') as product,
        MAX(missions_answerinteger.body) FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'amount') as amount,
        MAX(missions_answerinteger.body) FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'price') as "price"
from missions_answer 
    group by Response, product,amount, price
```

I'm getting this:

```
+   response    +     document    +    bill #  +    product  +  amount  +   price 
-   71788176    -     79907201    -    26899   -     shoes 2   -       10  -   32.99
```

It is kind of combining randomly the values, but I'm looking for this:

```
+   response    +     document    +    bill #  +    product  +  amount  +   price 
-   71788176    -     79907201    -    26899   -     shoes 1 -       1  -   25.99 
-   71788176    -     79907201    -    26899   -     shoes 2 -      10  -   32.00
```

Is there a way to get each product with the `amount` and `price` in different rows based on order given by `date` timestamp? I'm still unable to find a way, thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: Will they always have these milliseconds values? (00 for bill, 01 and 04 for product ...)

Comment: Should it not be SUM instead of MAX for the amount?

Comment: Add `date`(actually this is really datetime/timestamp) to the `group by` and then an ` order by Response, product,amount, price,date`

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks for your comment, miliseconds are variable, but they give me the order amount - product - price

Comment: So is your dataset always 3x+1 rows? eg first row bill# and then N number of triplet rows for product/amount/price?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, exactly

Comment: Is your sql incomplete ? It seems to reference tables that don't exists ?

Comment: Data is not correctly stored. Why are Bill# and Product not in each record or bill/product/amount/price not all in one record? Fix the data. Actually, should probably be two tables: Bills and dependent BillDetails.

Comment: A have a doubt that both queries are working at all, because there're references for tables not listed in `from` or `join` clauses. For ex: `crm_player`, `missions_answertext` and so on. Please, correct the question to have a correct answer.

Comment: And is it [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? Why do you ask for another question with the same context after you've marked the answer for your previous question as correct? Can you describe the whole task you want to accomplish? As long as you were provided a db<>fiddle in that question, it is not so hard to add the sample data and your query in it not to retype all the code for setup for this one

Comment: More questions: how do you want to identify that there should be two rows since there's no any clue between them? They all have the same `response` and `document`, datetime is different for all the rows. Looks like the model is inconsistent

Answer (score 1):

The problem I am seeing in this query:

```sql
select 
        missions_answer.response_id as Response,
        crm_player."document" as document,        
        MAX(missions_answertext.body) FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'bill #') as "bill #",
        MAX(missions_answerselectmultiple.body::json ->> 'name') FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'product') as product,
        MAX(missions_answerinteger.body) FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'amount') as amount,
        MAX(missions_answerinteger.body) FILTER (WHERE missions_question.label = 'price') as "price"
from missions_answer 
    group by Response, product,amount, price
```

Is that you are grouping by "amount" and "price" that are values calculated with an aggregation, I am not sure you can do this, but I am sure this is not a performant query.

I suggest to split the problem, to make it more performant and also more clear.

Use the Operator WITH (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html) or Subquerys to do it.

Also I suggest to review the data structure, using timestamps to match products and prices is awful at least.
Anyways you may try this to solve it:

```sql
WITH bills AS (
  SELECT response, bill_number
  FROM mission_answer
  WHERE missions_question.label = 'bill #'
)
, products AS (
  SELECT t1.response,
  t1.missions_question.label  as product,
  t2.price
  FROM mission_answer t1
  LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT temp.response, temp.date, temp.missions_answerinteger.body as price
    FROM mission_answer temp
    WHERE missions_question.label = 'price'
  ) t2
  ON t1.response = t2.response 
  AND t1.date = t2.date - '1 mili second'    --I am not sure about this sintax
  WHERE missions_question.label = 'product'
)

SELECT ...
FROM bills 
JOIN products
```